# How do I get rEFInd working with OS X 10.11 El Capitan?

Tags: startup, macos, dual-boot, efi

I noticed that I could not install and use rEFInd after upgrading to OS X 10.11 El Capitan. This restricts me to OS X so I cannot boot my Linux partition.

I get the following error: `error "Could not set boot device property: 0xe00002bc"`

Comment: I hope this gets more up votes, you definitely deserve it. +1 from me. This question is _rampant_ whenever I help people with dual-booting who have already "upgraded" to El Capitan.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You must disable System Integrity Projection.

1. Restart the computer, while booting hold down Command-R to boot into
   recovery mode.
2. Once booted, navigate to the “Utilities > Terminal” in the top menu bar.
3. Enter `csrutil disable` in the terminal window and hit the return key.
4. Restart the machine and System Integrity Protection will now be disabled.

source: http://mattjanik.ca/blog/2015/10/01/refind-on-el-capitan/

Comment: Note this method is out of date - there is no need to disable SIP - normal users shouldn't disable SIP - read the manual: http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/sip.html#recovery - or see other answers below (including from Rod himself)

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but I just had to go through this issue when attempting to install rEFInd on a 2015 MBP. When trying to install by running `./refind-install` in the terminal, I kept getting a message telling me that system integrity protection was enabled, and I could not do an install without rebooting into the recovery volume. The solution without disabling system integrity protection (it's probably there for a good reason):

1. In terminal, type `cd ~/Downloads`
2. Download the current install file with `curl -s -L https://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/files/0.10.3/refind-bin-0.10.3.zip`
3. `unzip refind-bin-0.10.3.zip`
4. Reboot, holding down `cmd + r` when the chime sounds
5. Open utilities -> Terminal
6. Your hard drive is no longer accessible at `/` since your on a different partition. Instead, it's now under /Volumes/{name of your hard drive}. If you don't already know what it's called (default is 'Macintosh\ HD'), type `cd /Volumes`, then `ls` to see it listed there.
7. Type `cd /Volumes/{name of your hard drive}/Users/{your username}/Downloads`. For example, mine is `cd /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/Ayden/Downloads`. Remember to escape all spaces in directory or filenames with '\ ', and use tab for autocompletion.
8. Type `./refind-install --root /Volumes/{Your hard drive} --yes`. You should get a successful completion notice.
9. Reboot. You should see rEFInd. To see the default boot manager, press the option key while booting.

Note: to see more install options type `vim refind-install` while in the `~/Downloads/refind-bin-0.10.3` directory. They are listed at the top. To quit vim, type `:q`.

Comment: I cannot find my directory at all from the recovery start. In /Volumes, I only have the `OSX Startup Disk` and `Untitled`, which I think is the new;y created space on the disk I made using Disc utility

Answer (score 3):

With the release of rEFInd 0.10.0, there's no official rEFInd documentation on this issue:

http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/sip.html

That version's installation script (now called `refind-install`) also runs from the Recovery HD, and rEFInd itself can manage SIP settings, which give two more options for how to work around the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, for example if you (like me) had removed the recovery partition before upgrading to El Capitan (which didn't restore it), boot into your [rEFInd USB stick](http://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/files/0.10.0/refind-flashdrive-0.10.0.zip/download), from there boot into Linux, install your rEFInd Linux package and install rEFInd back into your HD from Linux.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.zealpeal.com/dual-boot-os-x-el-capitan-on-macbook-pro-with-kali-linux/ check this full guide on dual booting os x el capitan and installing rEFInd.

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.